# Uploading a file using cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to upload a file using Cypress to a website. I know there is a cypress-file-upload import and a way to do it using something like:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="file-input"]')
  .attachFile('myfixture.json');
```

However, in the website I'm trying to load on, it does not have a "file-input" class. I have attached images of what I mean. There is nothing in the inspect element that has "file-input"

My question is, how would I go about uploading files in Cypress
[image]

Comment: You should try to find inside your DOM this kind of locator `<input type="file">` otherwise it is not gonna work, on your picture there is only `span` which is not responsible for uploading FYI

Comment: @Evgenii I am also facing this issue though I have input tag but it's disabled. Is there anyway to upload a file using <span> tag?

Comment: @Mr.PrasadJ first make sure we are on the same page because recently cypress provide file upload functionality from main library without installing cypress-upload plugin. Please follow the instruction https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide#Examples. And answering on your question, you should use `input` more details here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button